# WYSIWYG niceEdit editor does not work on textarea that are generated through ajax-php calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-editor, nicedit

I have a textarea that i am generating it with ajax, but after textarea is loaded then that textarea is not converting to WYSIWYG Editor, but it is working on normal textarea, Please help to solve my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
........
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/show_data",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data){

        $('#demo').html(data);
........
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
    <section id="demo">
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

> show_data.php

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Since I do not know, how you add the dynamic textarea, did you set "id" and "name" and can you find the object with javascript by "id" or "name"? Can you see the textarea with a DOM Inspector Tool in browser? It could be better to use document.ready function to tell niceditor the new textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `nicEditors.allTextAreas` again after inserting new textarea.

Comment: Thanks Justas. I used nicEditors.allTextAreas; in my success part of ajax but it did not work.